# Which countries have funding opportunities like ERC Advanced Grant?

Tags: funding, united-states, europe, canada, australia

The eligibility of ERC Advanced Grant is very interesting, everyone from anywhere can submit a proposal, and upon approval he should work in a host institution within European Union. This gives an excellent opportunities for independent researchers, as they do not need to be employed in Europe when applying.

Are other countries (mostly I mean, US, Canada and Australia) have such call for proposals, as anyone (regardless of location) can apply? Then, upon success, he should conduct the research in the funding country.

If yes, please name (or link) the specific call for proposal.

Comment: *"gives an excellent opportunities for independent researchers"* I have the impression you are severely underestimating how insanely competitive ERC Advanced Grants are. That is, getting such a grant is in no way an easier way to get a position in Europe - getting a permanent professorship is substantially easier than getting an Advanced Grant.

Comment: Since you have recently posted a whole array of questions re: advanced grants, I am assuming you want to submit to the mid-june deadline. **If you now have the questions you have, you should not submit.** You are late several months. Really. It will not work out.

Comment: Also, your bio says that "you completed 5 years of postdoctoral fellowships with success." That means you are *way* too young and inexperienced for an Advanced Grant. Please check the list of previous recipients: http://erc.europa.eu/projects-and-results/erc-funded-projects?f[2]=sm_field_cordis_project_funding%3AAdvanced%20Grant%20%28AdG%29 All recipients are full professors at the height of their career. Average h-indices hover in the 40-50 region. Based on your career stage you *may* apply for the Starting grant, *if you are really good*.

Comment: @xLeitix what I learned in academia is that we should try any possible opportunity, as the competition is high everywhere. I am applying for a permanent position now, but why not trying grants? The call says that its judgement is based on the track of last 10 years, and I think I have enough publications in that period to try my chance.

Comment: @xLeitix you may be right that I am late for the June call, but this question is about other funding opportunities. I am looking for new ones when I am not late.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that almost every country with a well-developed academic system has funding opportunities for researchers applying from abroad. Depending on the level of the applicant, that may range from a post-doctoral fellowship to funding for a research group of several persons over several years.

Although it doesn't address the specific countries you mention, there's for example

- the [Newton fellowship](http://www.britac.ac.uk/funding/guide/intl/newton_international_fellowships.cfm) in the UK,
- various programs by the [Humboldt foundation](http://www.humboldt-foundation.de/web/programmes-by-target-group.html) in Germany.

Generally, such programs require you to identify a host institution within the target country upon application, and to submit a confirmation by this institution that they're willing to host you (that's also how it works for the ERC grants, even for applicants from within the EU!).

In parallel to researching the funding options, I'd recommend to identify a host institution you'd like to work at and ask someone there what might be suitable funding instruments to apply for. Most researchers have a good overview of their national funding options, also those options that specifically address people coming from abroad.